# How not to finish "batch contextual actions" when all items deselected in Android Listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, multiple-select, contextual-action-bar, actionmode

I use "batch contextual actions" in a ListView in my Android app as it is described in the Android guide for menus:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

This is how I enable the contextual actions:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() { //...a lot of code});
```

This mode (some special menus showing) is activated when you make a long click on a list item and makes it possible for the user to make multiple selection. However the default behaviour of this action mode makes it finish/return when the user deselect all the items, which could be good but not what I want. I want the user himself to decide with the action menus when to end this mode.

Can you alter this default behaviour for "batch contextual actions" so that it don't finish when everything is deselected?

Best regards
/Tom

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Context Menu try ListPopUpWindow. Its easier to use and you can control when to dismiss the popup.